# Subscribe weakly to events obtained by reflection

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, weak-references

I'm making a `MessageBox` control in WPF using the MVVM pattern.  This `MessageBox` will be used in multiple applications with different appearances, so ideally I want to keep code out of code-behind.

I'm trying to make the `MessageBox` appear when an event is raised, specified in the declaration of the `MessageBox`.

For example, this would be specified in the XAML of the window in which the `MessageBox` should appear.

```
<dialog:MessageBox
    ShowOnEvent="EventRaised"
    EventContext="{Binding}"
    Message="I am a message box"
    IconType="Warning"
    ButtonsType="YesNo" />
```

The way this currently works: in the `MessageBox` ViewModel I'm using reflection to get the `EventInfo` for the event, then subscribing directly:

```
if (eventContext != null && showOnEvent != string.Empty)
{
    EventInfo eventInfo = eventContext.GetType ().GetEvent (showOnEvent);
    if (eventInfo != null)
    {
        eventInfo.AddEventHandler (eventContext, eventHandler);
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.WriteLine (string.Format ("Dialog: Couldn't find event {0} on {1}, check event name.", showOnEvent, eventContext));
    }
}
```

This shows the `MessageBox` when the event is raised, as expected.

**However**, the event handler means that the `MessageBox` ViewModel is not GC'd when the main window's View is disposed.  This means that if another view for the main window is created, another `MessageBox` is created, so if the event is raised, both `MessageBox`s will show.

I tried getting around this by using a `WeakEventManager`, but the [Weak Event Patterns documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970850.aspx) specify that an implementation of `WeakEventManager` should only handle one event - which means that I can't make a `ShowOnEventEventManager` with the event name as a string property and subscribe using that.

Does anyone have any ideas for the best way to go about this?

Comment: Is that control supposed to be an overlay, or does it bring up a `MessageBox`?

Comment: @Will: It's an overlay - the basic `MessageBox` is not really flexible enough for my needs.

Comment: Since you're subscribing to an event on the View, why not [subscribe to another event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.unloaded.aspx) as well, which will tell you when its time to unsubscribe to both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having a weak event won't solve your problem because you won't be unsubscribed until the GC decides to run (unless you're explicitly calling `GC.Collect()`). As Will suggests in the comments, you can try to unsubscribe at the appropriate time or what might be even easier is just have your MessageBox check if it `IsLoaded` before showing itself.

I wouldn't worry about code-behind in your MessageBox unless you know of some reason why it would hurt its reusability. It's fine to have MessageBox code reference its view directly as long as the consumers of the MessageBox have a MVVM-friendly API.

Comment: Thanks to you and @Will, listening to `Unloaded` worked a treat :)

Answer (score 0):

The [PRISM `EventAggregator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921122%28v=pandp.20%29.aspx) implements eventing using weak references by default. You need to be able to alter the code where events are published to implement this in your app.

There are proper code examples at the linked page as well as the obligatory flow diagrams. The event aggregator is fairly simple to use: you `Publish` with a strongly typed payload and `Subscribe` in as many places as you need. (And it's [free to download](http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/releases/view/55576))